# How to get a collection id of products from the basket ? Magento 2

Tags: magento2

```
 public function __construct(
            ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            RateErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
            Session $session,

            LoggerInterface $logger,
            RateResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
            RateMethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
            ProductFactory $productFactory,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_productFactory   = $productFactory;
            $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
            $this->_session = $session;
            $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
            parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
        }
 public function isActive()
    {

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/somelog.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        /** @var $item \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */
        $items = $this->_session->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $productid = $item->getProductId();

            $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($productid);
            $categoriesIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
```

here I only get the id of the first product from the basket, how to get all the id products from the basket

Comment: I don't know about this. But thanks for sharing this useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try THis For Get Basket Product :-**

```
protected $_cart;

public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart)
{ 
    $this->_cart = $cart;
}


public function yourfunction()
{
    $cartProductList = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

    foreach($cartProductList as $item) {

        echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';      

     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this to get all the basket productId
protected $_cart;

public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart)
{

```
$this->_cart = $cart;
```

}

public function yourfunction()
{

```
$cartProductId = $this->_cart->getQuoteProductIds();
```

//you will get array of product id

}